# How do I resolve timeout issue while connecting a AWS Lambda with EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-efs

I have ensure that the Lambda is in the same VPC as the EFS. Lambda has the same Security Group as the mounts. The mounts have all the permissions. However, when I run the Lambda function, it times out with following message  -
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The host did not accept the connection within timeout of 30000 ms.

The time out for lambda is set at 5 minutes.

Answer (score 4):

Resources in the same Security Group cannot communicate with each other unless a rule is added that explicitly allows the Security Group to communicate with "itself". This is because security groups are applied to each resource *individually*. There is no concept of multiple resources being "inside" a security group.

Instead, I would recommend creating:

- A **Security Group on the Lambda function** (`Lambda-SG`) with default "Allow All Outbound" settings
- A **Security Group on the EFS Mount Point** (`EFS-SG`) that permits inbound NFS access from `Lambda-SG`

That is, `EFS-SG` should specifically reference `Lambda-SG` in the inbound rules.

Answer (score 0):

After checking all your networking issues make sure to add a access point for EFS.

As well as you have to configure the lambda to use the EFS filesystem

[image]

You can always diagnose the issue further with VPC Flow logs on the ENI.